# Python - os.path does not recognize certain files on a network drive

Tags: python-2.7

I would think that the below code would return all `True`. Instead it returns a mixture of `True` and `False`. The files that `os` cannot locate do exists. Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

```
>>> dirPath = r"W:\Some\Path"
>>> os.path.isdir (dirPath)
True
>>> for di, sDi, files in os.walk (dirPath):
    for fil in files:
        filePath = os.path.join (di, fil)
        print os.path.exists (filePath)


False
False
True
False
True
True
...
```

`os.path.isfile` returns the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dirPath = r"W:/Some/Path"
```

or

```
dirPath = r"W:\\Some\\Path"
```